# Why its not printing Pyramid Triangle?

Tags: loops

```
def triangle(rows):
    num = rows
    
    for i in range(1 , rows +1 ):
        if i == num:
          print((x*2 - 1)* "*")
        else :
          print(" ", end= "")
      num -= 1
rows = int(input("How many rows of triangle?\n"))
triangle(rows)
```

Trial Answer:
First row has 1 star . Second row has 3 star . Third row has 5 star . Fourth row has 7 star and so on.

```
    *
   ***
   *****
   *******
   *********
```

Expected Answer:

```
    *
   ***
  *****
 *******
*********
```

Please Give me explanation where my code is wrong because of which I am not getting Answer

Comment: "where my code is wrong" - you're just printing the stars. You're not printing the leading whitespace.

Comment: What language is this? Is this pseudo code? What is x?